# How can i convert a categorical feature which contains strings to a numerical value in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

[enter image descripti[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bom99.png)on here][2]**Input**

for dataset in combine:`dataset['Sex'] = dataset['Sex'].map( {'female': 1, 'male': 0} ).astype(int)` `train.head()`

I want to convert  the sex category made up of males and females into numerical values

*This is the ValueError I have been getting below*

**ValueError:** Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

The picture to sample dataset
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYtpo2wxhiMuteIMjHHYOk93mty4deBe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure that all values are either male or female?

Comment: Please add a sample of your data set

Comment: Yes all values are either male or female

Comment: Sample of dataset https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYtpo2wxhiMuteIMjHHYOk93mty4deBe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The code you have used would work correctly if indeed all of the values are 'male' or 'female'.  However, if any of them aren't, then `map` will return `nan`, which would cause `astype(int)` to raise the `ValueError` you are receiving.  I've not seen a version of the Titanic dataset that doesn't have anything other than 'male' and 'female' for the `Sex` feature but that is the only explanation that makes sense here.  (By the way, using `astype(int)` here is redundant, since the mapping `dict` maps to integers anyway.)

Answer (score -1):

LabelEncoder() can do it for you. It is normally used to transform categorical variables to numeric. Check this article, the author uses it in the way you need. Link: 
https://towardsdatascience.com/encoding-categorical-features-21a2651a065c